# onClick Event Banner in Application Layout

Tags: xpages

I have got an application layout with an image as banner. Is it possible to bind an event handler with an onclick event to the image in the banner?

```
    <xe:applicationLayout id="applicationLayout1"><xp:this.facets></xp:this.facets>
        <xp:callback facetName="facetMiddle" id="facetMiddle"></xp:callback>
        <xe:this.configuration>
            <xe:oneuiApplication productLogo="/ise_logo.png"
                productLogoHeight="70px" productLogoWidth="250px">
                <xe:this.bannerUtilityLinks>
                </xe:this.bannerUtilityLinks>
                <xe:this.titleBarTabs>
                </xe:this.titleBarTabs>
                <xe:this.footerLinks>
                </xe:this.footerLinks>
            </xe:oneuiApplication>
        </xe:this.configuration>
        </xe:applicationLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a class to your logo as Application Layout Banner's parameter with `productLogoClass="applicationLogo"`.

[image]

Add then a client side onclick event for this class on client load with

```
    var applicationLogo= dojo.query('.applicationLogo')[0];
    applicationLogo.onclick = function() {
            alert('clicked on logo');
    }
```

In client side event code you can execute a partial refresh with XSP.partialRefreshGet or XSP.partialRefreshPost like shown [here](http://xpageswiki.com/web/youatnotes/wiki-xpages.nsf/dx/Work_with_events_and_partial_or_full_refresh).